# Jumping when user releases mouse button?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The script makes a GameObject jump using realistic gravity and reach a specific target. The GameObject jumps *relative* to the target, thus adjusting its trajectory. It also works while the target point is moving.

When the GameObject reaches the target, the target goes to a higher position (`position.y += 50`) and the GameObject jumps towards there. Thus, we have a "Continuous Jumping Cycle".

Script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Jumper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 _gravity = 9.8f * Vector3.down;
    public bool stillJumping = true;
    public GameObject Target1;

    public void SetVelocityToJump(GameObject goToJumpTo, float timeToJump)
    {
        StartCoroutine(jumpAndFollow(goToJumpTo, timeToJump));
    }

    private IEnumerator jumpAndFollow(GameObject goToJumpTo, float timeToJump)
    {
        var startPosition = transform.position;
        var targetTransform = goToJumpTo.transform;
        var lastTargetPosition = targetTransform.position;
        var initialVelocity = getInitialVelocity(lastTargetPosition - startPosition, timeToJump);

        var progress = 0f;
        while (progress < timeToJump)
        {
            progress += Time.deltaTime;
            if (targetTransform.position != lastTargetPosition)
            {
                lastTargetPosition = targetTransform.position;
                initialVelocity = getInitialVelocity(lastTargetPosition - startPosition, timeToJump);
            }

            transform.position = startPosition + (progress * initialVelocity) + (0.5f * Mathf.Pow(progress, 2) * _gravity);
            yield return null;
        }

        OnFinishJump(target, timeToJump);
    }

    private void OnFinishJump(GameObject target, float timeToJump)
    {
        if (stillJumping)
        {
            Vector3 temp1 = Target1.transform.position;
            temp1.y += 12.5f;
            Target1.transform.position = temp1;
            StartCoroutine(jumpAndFollow(target, timeToJump));
        }
    }

    private Vector3 getInitialVelocity(Vector3 toTarget, float timeToJump)
    {
        return (toTarget - (0.5f * Mathf.Pow(timeToJump, 2) * _gravity)) / timeToJump;
    }
}
```

With the script above, the GameObject always jumps from the position it has reached. That's what I mean by "Continuous Jumping Cycle"

JumpTarget's script:

```
public class JumpTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Jumper Jumper;
    public float TimeToJump;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (Jumper != null) Jumper.SetVelocityToJump(gameObject, TimeToJump);
    }
}
```

Here's the problem:  **How can we make GameObject continue to jump on `(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))` *every time* (not just the first jump)?** I can't quiet figure it out.

The following code is supposed to make this happen, but the GameObject doesn't even jump!

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && Jumper != null) Jumper.SetVelocityToJump(gameObject, TimeToJump);
```

I tried debugging, but, unfortunately, my Unity editor crashes every time.

EDIT: I've had complaints about my scripts working as they're supposed to on
`(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)`  If my scripts are working for you, please upload an example project, in which my scripts are working properly, as an answer. I suspect that my other scripts are interfering... Thanks.

Comment: Is your code using `Input.GetMouseButtonUp` in the `Update()` function of `JumpTarget`?

Comment: @Adam H Question edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "continue" jumping, use `GetMouseButton(...)` instead of `GetMouseButtonDown(...)` as the latter will only fire one time.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Jumper : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 _gravity = 9.8f * Vector3.down;
    public GameObject Target1;

    public void SetVelocityToJump(GameObject goToJumpTo, float timeToJump)
    {
        StartCoroutine(jumpAndFollow(goToJumpTo, timeToJump));
    }

    private IEnumerator jumpAndFollow(GameObject goToJumpTo, float timeToJump)
    {
        var startPosition = transform.position;
        var targetTransform = goToJumpTo.transform;
        var lastTargetPosition = targetTransform.position;
        var initialVelocity = getInitialVelocity(lastTargetPosition - startPosition, timeToJump);

        var progress = 0f;
        while (progress < timeToJump)
        {
            progress += Time.deltaTime;
            if (targetTransform.position != lastTargetPosition)
            {
                lastTargetPosition = targetTransform.position;
                initialVelocity = getInitialVelocity(lastTargetPosition - startPosition, timeToJump);
            }

            transform.position = startPosition + (progress * initialVelocity) + (0.5f * Mathf.Pow(progress, 2) * _gravity);
            yield return null;
        }

        OnFinishJump(target, timeToJump);
    }

    private void OnFinishJump(GameObject target, float timeToJump)
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector3 temp1 = Target1.transform.position;
            temp1.y += 12.5f;
            Target1.transform.position = temp1;
            StartCoroutine(jumpAndFollow(target, timeToJump));
        }
    }

    private Vector3 getInitialVelocity(Vector3 toTarget, float timeToJump)
    {
        return (toTarget - (0.5f * Mathf.Pow(timeToJump, 2) * _gravity)) / timeToJump;
    }
}

public class JumpTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Jumper Jumper;
    public float TimeToJump;

    public void Start()
    {
        if (Jumper != null && Input.GetMouseButton(0)) Jumper.SetVelocityToJump(gameObject, TimeToJump);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I said on `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)`. When the user releases the mouse button. That's my issue.

Comment: As I said before, The GameObject does not jump when the user releases the mouse button, with your code.

Comment: "The GameObject does not jump when the user releases the mouse button" is not a specific issue. I asked you 100 times if the code reaches the if statement and if `Jumper` is in fact not `null`. I don't think you are even trying to debug it. No one is going to make an example project because this isn't a code writing service.

Comment: I've told you two times that my Unity editor crashes when I try to debug. And I only have one computer... The best way for me right now would be to compare a working project to a non-working project.

Comment: The question is now on bounty if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34496400/jumping-on-input-getmousebuttonup0

Comment: Don't debug in Unity editor, debug in Monodevelop or Visual Studio. If you aren't debugging your code, then that means you aren't even attempting to help yourself. No one here likes to help people who don't attempt to help themselves. Asking for an example project, is asking for someone to create a working project for you, basically asking for someone to fix this whole thing for you and i'm not saying that i won't do it, i am saying that no one here is going to do that. All i can recommend for you is that if your debugging is bugging out on you, solve that problem and get to debugging.

Comment: Even if you can't attach a debugger, you can still add `Debug.Log` statements to determine things like whether your code reaches the if statement and whether `Jumper` is `null` or not.